# Horrifying electron gas model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, many-body, second-quantization

I am given the Hamiltonian, in an exercise called plasmons, and where $\langle, \rangle $ denotes the expectation value.

$$ H = \sum_{k} \varepsilon_k a_k^{\dagger} a_k + \sum_{k_1,k_2,q} V_q a_{k_1+q}^{\dagger} a_{k_2+q}^\dagger a_{k_2} a_{k_1}$$

and I am supposed to write down the time-dependence equation for $\langle a_{k-Q}^{\dagger} a_k \rangle$.

Now, I know that this is the Heisenberg equation of motion which is

$$-i \hbar \partial_t \langle a_{k-Q}^{\dagger} a_k \rangle = \langle [H,  a_{k-Q}^{\dagger} a_k ] \rangle $$ in that case.

I am supposed to end up with

$$- i \hbar \partial_t \langle a_{k-Q}^{\dagger} a_k \rangle = (\varepsilon_{k-Q} - \varepsilon_{k} ) \langle a_{k-Q}^{\dagger} a_k \rangle +V_Q(\langle a_{k}^{\dagger} a_k \rangle - \langle a_{k-Q}^{\dagger} a_{k-Q} \rangle ) \sum_{k_2} \langle a_{k_2-Q}^{\dagger} a_{k_2} \rangle + \sum_{q} V_q (\langle a_{k-q}^{\dagger} a_{k-q}  \rangle - \langle a_{k-Q+q}^{\dagger} a_{k-Q+q} \rangle)\langle a_{k-Q}^{\dagger} a_k \rangle$$

Now I actually managed to get the first two terms, but I don't see how to the potential:

$$+V_Q(\langle a_{k}^{\dagger} a_k \rangle - \langle a_{k-Q}^{\dagger} a_{k-Q} \rangle ) \sum_{k_2} \langle a_{k_2-Q}^{\dagger} a_{k_2} \rangle + \sum_{q} V_q (\langle a_{k-q}^{\dagger} a_{k-q}  \rangle - \langle a_{k-Q+q}^{\dagger} a_{k-Q+q} \rangle)\langle a_{k-Q}^{\dagger} a_k \rangle$$

We are also allowed to use Hartree Fock factorizations in the potential in order to avoid a coupling of the "calculated expectation values to higher expectation values", but I am not sure what this actually means.

From the lecture I would guess that this means something like $$\langle a_1^{\dagger} a_2^{\dagger} a_3 a_4 \rangle \sim \langle a_1^{\dagger}a_4 \rangle  \langle a_2^{\dagger} a_3 \rangle - \langle a_1^{\dagger} a_3 \rangle  \langle a_2^{\dagger} a_4 \rangle.$$

By the way: I have one rather simples questions about this:
Does anybody know if this model assumes that $k$ is discrete or continuous?

-(Maybe you could post this in the comments).

If anything is unclear please let me know.

Comment: As regarding to $\langle a^\dagger_{k-Q}a_l\rangle$ - I guess you problem is that you mess vacuum of the free Hamiltonian with the vacuum of the full system.  The first one is being annihilated by $a_k$, while the vacuum state for the full Hamiltonian is not.  The expression you are calcualting is in the vacuum of the full system.

Comment: not sure if I understand this. I mean, you just explained me that $a_l$ annihilates the states of the free part of the hamiltonian, right?  If I have now a product state $|n\rangle$ of these eigenfunctions, then $\langle n|a^{\dagger}_{k-Q} a_l|n \rangle $ is certainly always zero, but why is this now different in thsi case. What am I missing? How do I know what these operators do to the states of the full Hamiltonian ?

Comment: No. Example-state $|\psi\rangle=(a^\dagger_1+a^\dagger_2)|0\rangle$.  Then $\langle\psi|a^\dagger_2 a_1|\psi\rangle=1$

Comment: The problem is not horrifying, by the way. 
I think you are asked actually to perform a Hartree-Fock mean-field on the interacting electronic Hamiltonian. A detailed explanation can be found in H. Bruus and K. Flensberg, “Many-Body Quantum Theory in Condensed Matter Physics”, chp. 4 (“Mean field theory”).

Comment: The first equation looks wrong. How can the interaction increase the momentum of both interacting particles?

Comment: The title of this post is not helpful. Please use a more descriptive title.

Comment: I think your another question is obvious from the summation form the model uses; it certainly describes a system with discrete $k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say you "got the first to terms" I guess that means the non-interacting part. So, your trouble seems to be with the interaction terms. I don't want to work the whole thing out since this looks like homework, but maybe this will help:

Probably best to start by working out the commutator:
$$
[\sum_{k_1,k_2,q} V_q a_{k_1+q}^{\dagger} a_{k_2+q}^\dagger a_{k_2} a_{k_1},a_{k-Q}^\dagger a_{k}]
$$,
which it not really *so* horrible.

You can just repeatedly use the fact that:
$$
[AB,C] = A[B,C] + [A,C]B
$$

I think it might help to rewrite the commutator of interest like:
$$
[a^\dagger_1 a^\dagger_2 a_3 a_4,a_5^\dagger a_6]
$$
since it will make it harder to make transcription errors in the writing.

You can do this reduction many ways. For example, you could start off like:
$$
[a^\dagger_1 a^\dagger_2 a_3 a_4,a_5^\dagger a_6]
=
a^\dagger_1 [a^\dagger_2 a_3 a_4,a_5^\dagger a_6]
+
[a^\dagger_1 ,a_5^\dagger a_6]a^\dagger_2 a_3 a_4
$$
$$
=
a^\dagger_1 [a^\dagger_2 a_3 a_4,a_5^\dagger a_6]
+
a_5^\dagger[a^\dagger_1 , a_6]a^\dagger_2 a_3 a_4
$$
$$
=
a^\dagger_1 (a^\dagger_2[ a_3 a_4,a_5^\dagger a_6]+[a^\dagger_2 ,a_5^\dagger a_6]a_3 a_4)
+
a_5^\dagger[a^\dagger_1 , a_6]a^\dagger_2 a_3 a_4
$$
$$
=
a^\dagger_1 (a^\dagger_2[ a_3 a_4,a_5^\dagger ]a_6+a_5^\dagger[a^\dagger_2 , a_6]a_3 a_4)
+
a_5^\dagger[a^\dagger_1 , a_6]a^\dagger_2 a_3 a_4
$$
$$
=
a^\dagger_1 (a^\dagger_2(a_3[ a_4,a_5^\dagger ]+[ a_3 ,a_5^\dagger ]a_4)a_6+a_5^\dagger[a^\dagger_2 , a_6]a_3 a_4)
+
a_5^\dagger[a^\dagger_1 , a_6]a^\dagger_2 a_3 a_4
$$
$$
=
a^\dagger_1 (a^\dagger_2(a_3\delta_{4,5}+\delta_{35}a_4)a_6-a_5^\dagger\delta_{26}a_3 a_4)
-
a_5^\dagger\delta_{16}a^\dagger_2 a_3 a_4
$$
$$
=
 a^\dagger_1 a^\dagger_2 a_3 a_6\delta_{4,5}+a^\dagger_1 a^\dagger_2 a_4 a_6\delta_{35}-a^\dagger_1 a_5^\dagger a_3 a_4\delta_{26}
-
a_5^\dagger a^\dagger_2 a_3 a_4\delta_{16}
$$

Ok, so now what? I guess now you can start using the Hartree Fock approximation to figure out the expectation value for:
$$
< a^\dagger_1 a^\dagger_2 a_3 a_6\delta_{4,5}+a^\dagger_1 a^\dagger_2 a_4 a_6\delta_{35}-a^\dagger_1 a_5^\dagger a_3 a_4\delta_{26}
-
a_5^\dagger a^\dagger_2 a_3 a_4\delta_{16}
>$$

Then substitute back in the correct index names and do all the summations.